# How do I add a new type of renderable object to Three.js?

Tags: three.js

Specifically I need

1. interleaved data.

   I need my various attributes mostly all in the same buffer
   interleaved and not in separate buffers because I'll be updating
   most attributes together. Ideally I'd have one buffer with attribute1 and
   another buffer with attribute2, attribute3, attribute4, attribute5, interleaved.
2. the ability to only partially update buffers.

   My understanding of the current Three.JS code is that if I update vertex data
   it uploads all of it but I specifically only want to update a tiny portion. I
   can manage this myself assuming I can get Three.JS to do #1 and tell me where
   it made the buffers. Or if I can make the buffers myself and tell Three.js how
   to use them.
3. 100% custom attributes.

   None of my attributes are standard. No positions, normals, uvs, It's all special.
   This means for example THREE.js will not be able to look at my data to figure out
   a centroid or bounding box. If it needs that data I'll need to supply it.

If there's an example that already does this just point me to it. Looking at the examples folder though I didn't see one. A grep through the three.js code didn't bring up any calls to vertexAttribPointer with custom offsets. Is this something I'd have to add?

Comment: I don't think none of that is currently supported. Maybe you can post it as a feature request? https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow. Should I write that as an answer instead of as a comment?

Comment: I think save answering for after the feature is added. Then there will be an answer :-)